# Illustrator skew only one corner of the object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, skew

I just want to know how to skew only one corner of the object specially a none square object using Selection Tool (V) or Direct Selection Tool (A). I just want the letter A look like its fell. Please help. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This image will give you the idea of what you are trying to achieve.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is the shortcut for Free Disort Tool after pressing E on transform?

Comment: @Liky click a handle THEN hold down Command/Ctrl. There are no direct shortcut for the option, but modifier keys make the options function.